# Knockout observablearray of observables with arrayMap function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a problem creating observable array of observables. I search on google but didn't find a solution. It may be something simple that I can't notice, because I'm new to Knockout. 
But I have the model:

```
eventsModel = function () {
   var self = this;

   self.endTimeInMinutes = ko.observable();
   self.events = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.startTripTime = ko.observable();
   self.endTripTime = ko.observable();
}
```

and I want to have an observables items in my array so I write a ViewModel and bind the model.

```
eventItemViewModel = function(o) {
    var self = this;

    self.BeginInMinutes = ko.observable(o.BeginInMinutes);
    self.Type = ko.observable(o.Type);
};

var events = new eventsModel();
ko.applyBindings(events);
```

And I'm fetching the data using AJAX:

```
function GetEvents() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Contact.aspx/GetEvents",
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var temp = data.d;
            endTimeInMinutes = temp["EndInMinutes"];
            eventsArr = temp["Events"];
            eventsArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eventsArr));
            events.events(eventsArray);
        },
    });
}
```

After this I have an observable array but without observables values inside. Now I trying to add in my AJAX method:

```
events.events(ko.utils.arrayMap(eventsArray, function(eve) {return new eventItemViewModel(eve); }));
```

But if I do `console.log` on this, then I am getting array of objects, and in each object there is a `BeginInMinutes` and Type, but it's value is like `function d()... etc`.

I'm really get stucked with it, and I believe I made some very simple mistake somewhere.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: what do you want exactly, Do you want the items in the `observableArray` to be `observable` or just `js object` ? I think the question is not very clear

Comment: by the way, the result which you get `function d()` is an evidence that you have an `observable` objects in the `observableArray`. Is it what you already want ??

Comment: put the code that you are using for the Console.log, you have to call that function to get the data of the `BeginInMinutes`

Comment: Ok, so if it's an evidence, then maybe the problem is how to show the exact data instead of showing function d().... In the console.log the data is located under [[Scopes]] -> Closure. So maybe my problem is about to show this proper data, if you say that it's already an observableArray of observables.

Comment: you can show your data by the following command `BeginInMinutes()`, just add the parentheses to the name of the property.

Comment: Calling it like this: `console.log(events.events().BeginInMinutes);` returns undefined, and calling BeginInMinutes with parentheses returns that it is not a function.

Comment: `console.log(events.events()[0].BeginInMinutes());` this will get the value of the first element in the array.

Comment: Ok, it works, maybe now I can go further, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got an `observableArray` with `observable` element inside it,
Your problem really is with getting those values

use this code to get the real value of the first element in the array.

```
console.log(events.events()[0].BeginInMinutes());
```